# CUDA only recognizes 1 of 5 GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

I would like to run tensorflow on a windows 10 server with 5 NVIDIA Quadro P6000 GPUs. After installing CUDA 8.0 and running deviceQuery.exe it only shows one of the GPUs and therefore tensorflow only uses one GPU as well.

```
(tensorflow-gpu) C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\extras\demo_suite>deviceQuery.exe
deviceQuery.exe Starting...

CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "Quadro P6000"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          8.0 / 8.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 24576 MBytes (25769803776 bytes)
  (30) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     3840 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1645 MHz (1.64 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             4513 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              384-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 3145728 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(131072), 2D=(131072, 65536), 3D=(16384, 16384, 16384)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(32768), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(32768, 32768), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  CUDA Device Driver Mode (TCC or WDDM):         WDDM (Windows Display Driver Model)
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 4 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 8.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 8.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = Quadro P6000
Result = PASS
```

However, nvidia-smi.exe and GPU-Z do recognize all 5 of them.

```
(tensorflow-gpu) C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI>nvidia-smi.exe
Wed Sep 27 11:07:44 2017
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 376.51                 Driver Version: 376.51                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P6000       WDDM  | 0000:04:00.0     Off |                  Off |
| 26%   45C    P5    19W / 250W |    353MiB / 24576MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Quadro P6000       WDDM  | 0000:05:00.0     Off |                  Off |
| 26%   24C    P8     7W / 250W |     69MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Quadro P6000       WDDM  | 0000:08:00.0     Off |                  Off |
| 26%   26C    P8     8W / 250W |     69MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Quadro P6000       WDDM  | 0000:09:00.0     Off |                  Off |
| 26%   26C    P8     8W / 250W |     69MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  Quadro P6000       WDDM  | 0000:89:00.0     Off |                  Off |
| 26%   22C    P8     8W / 250W |    262MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      2640  C+G   Insufficient Permissions                     N/A      |
|    0      3908  C+G   ...x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe N/A      |
|    4      2640  C+G   Insufficient Permissions                     N/A      |
|    4      3552  C+G   ...\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe N/A      |
|    4      5260  C+G   Insufficient Permissions                     N/A      |
|    4      6552  C+G   Insufficient Permissions                     N/A      |
|    4      7208  C+G   ...ost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe N/A      |
|    4      7444  C+G   ...indows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Does anyone have an idea what I could try to make all of them work for CUDA and tensorflow?

Comment: possibly an errant [environment variable setting](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars).  Are you actually launching `deviceQuery` from within TF?  If so, what happens if you just run `deviceQuery` normally, from system command prompt?

Comment: So far I've only set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to 0,1,2,3,4. Unfortunately deviceQuery has the same Output when I start it from either.

Comment: I would suggest rebooting the machine and then running `deviceQuery` from a new command prompt/shell.  At that point, if you don't see 5 GPUs reported, check device manager for any issues reported with any of the 5 display adapters.

Comment: the device manager does not report anything other than driver installations and reboots don't change the output either.

Comment: after reinstalling CUDA deviceQuery.exe shows every GPU. But if I activate tensorflow-gpu it goes back to only one. I have to reboot the whole system to make it show all five GPUs again. I will try to reinstall tensorflow

Comment: unfortunately reinstalling tensorflow didn't change anything. furthermore I noticed that the devicequery output is not always right after a reboot.

Comment: sounds like you have an unstable system which is not designed to support 5 P6000 GPUs.

Comment: but on ubuntu 16.04 everything works. i'll probably just use this setup for now.